# Save files with vba (special)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to have a button which opens a window like the "save as" window, then you can choose a file in this window (no folder or name) and by clicking on "save" the system should save the choosen file at a defined folder with defined name.

Is there a way to do it like this?

Comment: Yes. You can use the [`FileDialog Object`](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s209/type-filedialog.htm) to pick a file or folder and for instance use [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/vba/filesystemobject-vba-examples/#copyfile) to copy that file.

Comment: Thank you, it´s working. How can we Close this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved like this:

```
Function adding(addval)
Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim FileChosen As Integer

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

FileChosen = fDialog.Show

    If FileChosen <> -1 Then
        'clicked on CANCEL
        Exit Function
    End If

Me.Controls("Q" & addval & "Link").Caption = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End Function
```